# Reactjs map method pick unique id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my react app I have a map method like this:

```
data.qandASections.map((item, i) => {
    return (
        <div className="qaElement" key={i} onClick={showAnswer(i)}>
           <div className="question">
               <span>{item.question}</span>
               <span className="arrowDown" id={"arrow"+i}></span>
           </div>
           <div className="answer" id={"answer"+i} style={{display: "none"}}>{item.answer}</div>
        </div>
      )
})
```

I want to access in the function showAnswer the unique ids that I created (answer0,answer1 .... answern)

The function looks like this

```
function showAnswer(i){
        const answerId = "answer" + i
        const arrowId = "arrow" + i
        const answer = document.getElementById(answerId)
        const arrow = document.getElementById(arrowId)

        if (answer.style.display = "none") {
            answer.style.display = "block"
            arrow.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)"
        } else {
            answer.style.display = "none"
            arrow.style.transform = "rotate(-135deg)"
        }
    }
```

Sadly this doesn't work as I get "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'style' of null" for the id elements which i created in the map function ("answer"+i) and ("arrow"+i)
Is there any other way to get access to these elements?

Comment: i wouldn't use direct dom maniuplation like that for react

Comment: Agree with @DanielA.White , what is point of using react than

Comment: hello, a few things to note:  

Please don't use i as a key, because it may change with every render and breaks the whole reason react uses keys with mapped arrays.

It's probably easier to create a Question component that manages its own state to show and hide the answer.

Also, what @DanielA.White mentioned, setting styles on the component in the way you have done is not a good way to use react.  Try using the ClassNames library to apply styles through CSS or use something else to set the styles (maybe StyledComponents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this string:

```
<div className="qaElement" key={i} onClick={showAnswer(i)}>
```

to this:

```
<div className="qaElement" key={i} onClick={() => showAnswer(i)}>
```